# How to call web services from WSDL?

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have save the wsdl into my local computer, so I have create a new project with visual studio (c#) then I have import this file. So I have the WSDL into my project and I have PianoResidentialService under "Service Refereces" folder.

Now I want to try to call a web service. But I don't know how do this.
I have try this code but now works.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.getPianoAssistenziale ws_PA = new PianoAssistenzialeResidenzialeService.getPianoAssistenziale();

}
```

If I try to get Inspect ws_PA, all field is null.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the endpoint:

```
ws_PA.URL = "http://some.server.com/endpoint/";
```

Then, you should call a method which is generated for the operation you want to call. (Remember that a webservice can have multiple operations.)

```
var result = ws_PA.Operation(parameters);
```

You might want to share the WSDL with us and tell us in more detail what you want to achieve.